# How to apply stored index to another div?

Tags: jquery

I have a following problem here: in my html structure I got some div's and they are initially hidden. What I am trying to do is this: on click of a paragraph tag store it's index and apply that same index to hidden div (witch also has the same index as "clicked" p tag).

**For example:** when I click SHOW RED DIV 'paragraph' show the hidden div **(div with class red)** with the same index as clicked p tag. My code is not working because it shows all hidden div's and because I don't know how to apply stored index :(   I hope that someone can help me... THX!! 
Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJ5Gs/)

This is what I got so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div{width:100px;height:100px;display:none;}
.red{background-color:red;}
.blue{background-color:blue;}
.green{background-color:green;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("p").click(function(){
   var index=$(this).index(this);
   $('div').data('index',index).show('slow');
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<span>
<p>SHOW RED DIV</p>
<p>SHOW BLUE DIV</p>
<p>SHOW GREEN DIV</p>
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").click(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('div:eq(' + index + ')').show('slow');
    });
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q96Uj/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").click(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('div').eq(index).show('slow');
    });
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/YAeWg/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
     var index=$(this).index();
      $('div:eq('+ index +')').show('slow');
  });
});
```

check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DJ5Gs/2/)**

Comment: didn't downvote, but links are invalid answers in SO. copy the code to your answer, and hope the downvoter will revert it.

Answer (score 1):

Woah, some confusion here. The `index` is the index of an element relative to its siblings. The index you're attempting to look up via `data` is an arbitrary index you've defined and attached to the elements as follows:

```
<div class="red" data-index="red"></div>
<p data-index="red">SHOW RED DIV</p>
```

Vision's answer provides the correct way to access elements using the `index()` function, but for your application it sounds like you might prefer to use user-defined indexes. If that's the case, your javascript will look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    var index=$(this).data('index');
    $('div[data-index=' + index + ']').show('slow');
  });
});​
```